# Como retornar um vetor de char numa função em C? tipo como um ponteiro

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando retornar um vetor que recebe o conteúdo de uma matriz numa função, mas não está dando certo, agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar, estou com essa dúvida

**Chamada da função na main:**

```
char vetor[tamMsg*9];
retornar_vetor(&mensagem, &vetor);
```

**A função:**

```
char*  retornar_vetor(char **mensagem, char **vet) {
    int i, j;
    char cpy[2];
    int tamanhoMsg = strlen(*mensagem);
    char str[tamanhoMsg][9];


    for(i=0; i<tamanhoMsg; i++){
        str[i][0] = '\0';
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            sprintf(cpy,"%d", (*mensagem)[i]%2);
            strcat(str[i], cpy);
            vetor[j] = str[i]
            (*mensagem)[i]/=2;
        }
        str[i][j] = '\0';
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }

return vet;
    printf("\n");
}
```

Obs: O foco da questão é conseguir colocar os valores da matriz `str` no vetor e retornar para o vetor na main, por isso o ponteiro de ponteiro, não tô conseguindo entender como fazer

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida. Está tendo algum problema? Como está o resto, o problema talvez seja em como está consumindo. De qualquer forma tenho quase certeza que isso já foi respondido antes.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o seu racíocinio original, segue um exemplo (testado) de como concatenar e retornar em um vetor cada mensagem contida em um outro vetor de ponteiros (mensagens):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void retornar_vetor( char ** mensagem, char ** ret )
{
    int i = 0;

    while( mensagem[i] )
        strcat( *ret, mensagem[i++] );
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char * msgs[] = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Episilon", "Zeta", "Eta", "Theta", NULL };
    char vetor[100] = {0};

    char * paux = &vetor[0];

    retornar_vetor( msgs, &paux );

    printf("%s\n", vetor );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./vetor_v1 
AlphaBetaGammaDeltaEpisilonZetaEtaTheta
```

Existe uma maneira mais elaborada de resolver o problema com alocação dinâmica de memória com as funções `malloc()`, `realloc()` e `free()`, segue outro exemplo (testado):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void retornar_vetor( char ** mensagem, char ** ret )
{
    int i = 0;
    char * p = NULL;
    size_t len = 0L;

    p = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) );

    *p = 0;

    if( !mensagem )
    {
        *ret = p;
        return;
    }

    while( mensagem[i] )
    {
        len += strlen( mensagem[i] );

        p = realloc( p, len + 1 );

        strncat( p, mensagem[i], len );

        i++;
    }

    *ret = p;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char * msgs[] = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Episilon", "Zeta", "Eta", "Theta", NULL };

    char * vet = NULL;

    retornar_vetor( msgs, &vet );

    printf("%s\n", vet );

    free(vet);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./vetor_v2 
AlphaBetaGammaDeltaEpisilonZetaEtaTheta
```

Answer (score 0):

A variável "vet" é do tipo ponteiro de ponteiro, então deves retornar o mesmo tipo.

Ex:

```
char  **retornar_vetor(char **mensagem, char **vet){

   .
   .
   .
   .

   return vet;

}
```

Ao receber valor da função deves também armazenar numa variável do mesmo tipo.